# Dissolving Multiple Ring Buffer by Buffer Ring Iteration Order using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, buffer

I have a lines feature class with the following attribute table:

[image]

When I run the **MultipleRingBuffer_analysis** function using the following code (provided by user @Emil Brundage), buffers are drawn using the sum of the "width" column of the attribute table and a list of distances 10, 20 and 30 meters.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/Py.gdb"
fc = "lines"
distances = [10,20,30]
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference
#create feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("C:/data/Py.gdb",
                                     "Multibuffers",
                                     "POLYGON",
                                     spatial_reference = sr)
#insert cursor to insert geometries into feature class
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor ("Multibuffers", ["SHAPE@"]) as iCurs:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@', 'width','OID@']) as cursor:
        for geom, width, oid in cursor:
            #buffer in memory
            arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(Input_Features=geom,
                                             Output_Feature_class=r'in_memory\buffs',
                                             Distances=[i+width for i in distances],
                                             Buffer_Unit='meters')

            #iterate buffers and add to output feature class
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (r'in_memory\buffs', ["SHAPE@"]) as sCurs:
                for row in sCurs:
                    iCurs.insertRow (row)

            #delete in memory buffers
            arcpy.Delete_management (r'in_memory\buffs')
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

Output is one non dissolved feature class containing all the buffers as POLYGON objects (screenshot 1). I need to find a way to dissolve the buffers by ring iteration order in order to obtain something similar as screenshot 2 but with the right distances applied.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant dissolve by buffer width since each feature has different widths. Add a counting field so first buffer gets count 1, second 2, third 3 and dissolve by this:

```
import arcpy

infc = r'C:\database.gdb\lines'
outfc = r'C:\database.gdb\buffers'
name_of_width_field = 'width'

distances = [100,200,300]

arcpy.env.workspace = r'in_memory'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, ['SHAPE@', name_of_width_field,'OID@']) as cursor:
    for geom, width, oid in cursor:
        name = r'Multibuffer_{0}'.format(oid)
        arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(Input_Features=geom, 
                                         Output_Feature_class=name, 
                                         Distances=[i+width for i in distances], 
                                         Buffer_Unit='meters', 
                                         Dissolve_Option='NONE')
        arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=name, field_name='count', 
                                 field_type='SHORT')
        c = 1
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(name,'count') as cursor2:
            for row2 in cursor2:
                row2[0]=c
                cursor2.updateRow(row2)
                c+=1
arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(), output='Before_dissolve')
arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features='Before_dissolve', out_feature_class=outfc, 
                         dissolve_field='count')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BERA. Every time a buffer is drawn, the UpdateCursor give a value to the new added field, the value been dependent upon which i in distance the first loop in working one? I just began Python, trying to understand ;)

Comment: Yes. The order of the output of multibuffer is shortest buffer to longest buffer so it is just a matter of adding a field and calculate a Count.