# Dissolving multiple overlapping ring buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dissolve, polygon-creation, buffer

I am creating multiple ring buffers around polygon areas of interests. Due to their proximity, some of these are overlapping. I would like to dissolve them into joined features.

[image]

I have tried dissolve using the buffer distance as dissolve field, but it does not quite get the result I am after:

[image]

I would like to keep the inner area on top working towards the outside if that makes sense to get a clean polygon.

I found the below for ArcGIS, but am after a solution in QGIS, if anyone has thoughts?

[Dissolving Multiple Ring Buffer by Buffer Ring Iteration Order using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269820/dissolving-multiple-ring-buffer-by-buffer-ring-iteration-order-using-arcpy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mind started working properly and I found the solution right after posting: Dissolve first, then do the buffer...

Answer (score 2):

You can buffer while ticking the 'dissolve' option to do the trick in one round.

Comment: That only seems to be an option for the standard buffer function not the multiple ring buffers?

Comment: I see the point, you are right and that could become a feature request: I think many users would find a dissolvable multiring buffer a useful function.